# How can this dom-to-vars code be shortened in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Just found this code in a YouTube tutorial and found it to be very verbose:

[image: Verbose JS code]

So I thought, can't this be shortened? Isn't there some kind of ES2015 magic or so that can make this a one-liner?

The smartest that I could come up with was this:

```
const els = ['txtEmail', 'txtPassword', 'btnLogin', 'btnSignUp', 'btnLogout'];
const values = {};
for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
  values[els[i]] = document.getElementById(els[i]);
}
```

This isn't much shorter but if there were more dom elements this would definitely pay off in the long run.

However, how can this be optimized to be as non-verbose as possible?

Comment: @Rajesh As I said, this is from a YouTube tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKrloDzGpU - For the answer of the question this is irrelevant though.

Comment: Create a function `const getById = id => document.getElementById(id)` - less typing in the future for sure.

Comment: Don't get bogged down in shortening everything.  It's very often a bad thing to do.  One line of code per declaration is perfectly okay, and it's very simple to see what it does.  Make a loop or function and the next person to read it will have to figure out what it does.

Comment: @Archer Sure, but what if there were like 50 form fields. That sure would get nasty..

Comment: The browser doesn't care when it runs it.  Don't get me wrong - I'm not saying this is wrong.  It's just not always appropriate and in the example you've given it isn't.  If you did want to get 50 form fields then I wouldn't be asking how to do it with less code.  I'd be asking if it's the right approach to solve whatever problem the form with 50 fields is needed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a list of elements with `map`.

```
const ids = ["txtEmail", "txtPassword", "btnLogin", "btnSignUp", "btnLogout"];
const elems = ids.map(id => document.getElementById(id));
```

Or you could make an object with `reduce`.

```
const ids = ["txtEmail", "txtPassword", "btnLogin", "btnSignUp", "btnLogout"];
const elems = ids.reduce((obj, id) => {
    obj[id] = document.getElementById(id);
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

With reduce

```
const els = ['txtEmail', 'txtPassword', 'btnLogin', 'btnSignUp', 'btnLogout'];
const elms = els.reduce( (o, id) => { 
  o[id] = document.getElementById(id); 
  return o
}, {} )
```

without the fat arrow

```
const els = ['txtEmail', 'txtPassword', 'btnLogin', 'btnSignUp', 'btnLogout'];
const elms = els.reduce( function (o, id) { 
  o[id] = document.getElementById(id); 
  return o
}, {} )
```

In the end, not sure what the benefit of it is....

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
var fields={
txtEmail,
txtPassword
}

Object.keys(fields).forEach(e=>fields[e]=document.getElementById(e));

console.log(fields.txtEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment

```js
const [txtEmail, txtPassword, btnLogin, btnSignUp, btnLogout] = [
      document.getElementById("txtEmail")
      , document.getElementById("txtPassword")
      , document.getElementById("btnLogin")
      , document.getElementById("btnSignUp")
      , document.getElementById("btnLogout")
      ];

console.log(txtEmail, txtPassword, btnLogin, btnSignUp, btnLogout);
```

```html
<input id="txtEmail">
<input id="txtPassword">
<input id="btnLogin">
<input id="btnSignUp">
<input id="btnLogout">
```

Alternatively, using `.querySelectorAll()` with attribute begins with selector and spread element

```js
const [txtEmail, txtPassword, btnLogin, btnSignUp, btnLogout] = [
      ...document.querySelectorAll("input[id^=txt]")
      , ...document.querySelectorAll("input[id^=btn]")
      ];
      
console.log(txtEmail, txtPassword, btnLogin, btnSignUp, btnLogout);
```

```html
<input id="txtEmail">
<input id="txtPassword">
<input id="btnLogin">
<input id="btnSignUp">
<input id="btnLogout">
```